# Excel VBA Range.MoveEndUntill "," or ";" or " "; which ever comes first?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel macro to extract email addresses from the word document. At first I find @ sign in the document and later I'm moving towards the end of the email address that has this @ inside.

In most cases the email addresses end with a "," but because the docs are created by many different people, therefore sometimes the email addresses end with ";" (a semicolon) or only a " " (a space).

This is the code I use:

```
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document        'and it's concatenating them into the destination string variable
Dim excelApp As Excel.Application   'sometimes this code grabs the next line after the last email address, which is the first line of the next patagraph "2. Wszelka korespondencja związana z wykonaniem niniejszej umowy, w tym "
Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim srchRng As Word.Range

With rng.Find
        .Text = "@"                 'we only look for the @ character,
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Execute
        'Debug.Print rng.text
        
        Do While .Found             'therefore we need to build whole email addres around this @ character;
            Set srchRng = rng.Duplicate
            srchRng.MoveStartUntil Cset:=" ", Count:=wdBackward      'therefore we need to build whole email addres around this @ character;
            srchRng.MoveEndUntil Cset:=","            'ask the question how to MoveEndUntil "," or ";" or ".";
            Debug.Print srchRng.Text
```

The question is how to write the code that in case there is no "," after the email address, the macro checks if there is ";" and

```
srchRng.MoveEndUntil Cser:=";"
```

and if there's neither "," or ";" then the macro finds the first space to the right of @ and moves towards it,

```
srchRng.MoveEndUntil Cser:=" "
```

Is there a way to put it into one or 2 simple VBA lines.

The problem is, that now, in the current form there is always a coma somewhere after the email address, so if the coma is not directly after the email address, than the macro captures the email address and few other words to the right, which is not what I intend.

I've also tried the code:

```
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document        'and it's concatenating them into the destination string variable
Dim excelApp As Excel.Application   'sometimes this code grabs the next line after the last email address, which is the first line of the next patagraph "2. Wszelka korespondencja związana z wykonaniem niniejszej umowy, w tym "
Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim srchRng As Word.Range

With rng.Find
        .Text = "@"                 'we only look for the @ character,
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Execute
        'Debug.Print rng.text
        
        Do While .Found             'therefore we need to build whole email addres around this @ character;
            Set srchRng = rng.Duplicate
            srchRng.MoveStartUntil Cset:=" ", Count:=wdBackward      'therefore we need to build whole email addres around this @ character;
            srchRng.MoveEndWhile Cset:=" ,;", Count:=wdForward 
            Debug.Print srchRng.Text
```

This code isn't moving end any character. The mail address stays like sekretariat@ or spinn2046@ or johnnycash@  without the domain address.

I write this code in excel VBA editor if it makes any difference.

Comment: Use .Moveendwhile cset=" ,;"

Comment: Alternatively use a wildcard search. ([! ])(@)([! ;,]) or something similar.

Comment: hey @freeflow. I'd like to use your hint: ```srchRng.Moveendwhile cset:=" ,;"``` but it doesny work for me. Why is that?? Wait 20 minutes and I'll update the info in the main question.

Comment: Probably because moveendwhile needs a ranghe that encompasses the whole of your email address, not just the '@', hence the second suggestion for a wildcard search to capture the whole address in one go.

Comment: The answer was even simpler than your first suggestion @freeflow: ```srchRng.MoveEndUntil cset:=" ,;", Count:=wdForward```  I just didn't know I can put more signs in between the quotation marks. Everything works fine now  :-)

Comment: F1 is your friend

Answer (score 1):

Before you start extracting emails change **all** occurances of semicolons and spaces to commas and **after you finish close the document without saving**.

```
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document        'and it's concatenating them into the destination string variable
Dim excelApp As Excel.Application   'sometimes this code grabs the next line after the last email address, which is the first line of the next patagraph "2. Wszelka korespondencja związana z wykonaniem niniejszej umowy, w tym "
Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim srchRng As Word.Range

' Replace All ; to ,
rng.Text = Replace(rng.Text, ";", ",")

' Replace All spaces to ,
' Note: Cset:="," even for the beginning of email now
rng.Text = Replace(rng.Text, " ", ",")

' Similarly replace any other possible character to a comma

With rng.Find
        .Text = "@"                 'we only look for the @ character,
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Execute
        'Debug.Print rng.text
        
        Do While .Found             'therefore we need to build whole email addres around this @ character;
            Set srchRng = rng.Duplicate
            srchRng.MoveStartUntil Cset:=",", Count:=wdBackward      'therefore we need to build whole email addres around this @ character;
            srchRng.MoveEndUntil Cset:=","            'ask the question how to MoveEndUntil "," or ";" or ".";
            Debug.Print srchRng.Text
```

This is probably not the most efficient way, but it should get the job done.